# How can I align these two graphs by their y axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, align

How do I align these two graphs vertically? Their y axis are not [image]aligned and that's annoying me. Also, I've tried "[trim axis left,trim axis right,baseline]" as I've read here but it doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[trim axis left,trim axis right,baseline,
            height=6cm, width=.95\textwidth, axis lines=middle,
            ytick={0},
            xlabel={$x$}, xmax=1.2, axis on top
            ]
                \addplot[samples=100, domain=0:1,]{sin(deg(2*x*pi))};
                \path[fill=gray!10] (1,-1)--(1,1)--(1.2,1)--(1.2,-1);
                \draw (1,-1) -- (1,1);
            \end{axis}      
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[trim axis left,trim axis right,baseline,
            height=6cm, width=.95\textwidth, axis lines=middle,
            ytick={0},
            xlabel={$x$}, xmax=1.2, axis on top
            ]
                \addplot[samples=100, domain=0:1]{(sin(deg(2*x*pi)))^2};
                \path[fill=gray!10] (1,-1)--(1,1)--(1.2,1)--(1.2,-1);
                \draw (1,-1) -- (1,1);
            \end{axis}      
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The misalignment is due to the labels below the axis, since the default is to align the bottoms `(current bounding box.south)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move images baselines to their vertical centers. This anticipated that height of both image is the same. However, this seems not to be a case, so try to move baseline to top of images and also align `subfigure`s with their top:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
            \begin{axis}[trim axis left,trim axis right,baseline,
            height=6cm, width=.95\textwidth, axis lines=middle,
            ytick={0},
            xlabel={$x$}, xmax=1.2, axis on top
            ]
                \addplot[samples=100, domain=0:1,]{sin(deg(2*x*pi))};
                \path[fill=gray!10] (1,-1)--(1,1)--(1.2,1)--(1.2,-1);
                \draw (1,-1) -- (1,1);
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
            \begin{axis}[trim axis left,trim axis right,baseline,
            height=6cm, width=.95\textwidth, axis lines=middle,
            ytick={0},
            xlabel={$x$}, xmax=1.2, axis on top
            ]
                \addplot[samples=100, domain=0:1]{(sin(deg(2*x*pi)))^2};
                \path[fill=gray!10] (1,-1)--(1,1)--(1.2,1)--(1.2,-1);
                \draw (1,-1) -- (1,1);
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[trim axis left,trim axis right,baseline,
            height=6cm, width=.95\textwidth, axis lines=middle,
            ytick={0},
            xlabel={$x$}, xmax=1.2, axis on top
            ]
                \addplot[samples=100, domain=0:1,]{sin(deg(2*x*pi))};
                \path[fill=gray!10] (1,-1)--(1,1)--(1.2,1)--(1.2,-1);
                \draw (1,-1) -- (1,1);
            \end{axis}      
          \end{tikzpicture}
          \vspace{6.2mm}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[trim axis left,trim axis right,baseline,
            height=6cm, width=.95\textwidth, axis lines=middle,
            ytick={0},
            xlabel={$x$}, xmax=1.2, axis on top
            ]
                \addplot[samples=100, domain=0:1]{(sin(deg(2*x*pi)))^2};
                \path[fill=gray!10] (1,-1)--(1,1)--(1.2,1)--(1.2,-1);
                \draw (1,-1) -- (1,1);
            \end{axis}      
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```